# JavaFX: Not able to put Label inside of GridPane

Tags: gridview, text, label, javafx-2

I am trying to put a Label inside of GridPane in JavaFX.

I have following code:

```
@FXML
private Label nameCheck;

@FXML 
private GridPane gridPane;

gridPane.add(nameCheck, 0, 0);
```

But, when I am trying to do so, it is giving me error saying:
`The method add(Node, int, int) in the type GridPane is not applicable for the arguments (Label, int, int)`

When I tried to put `Text` inside of `GridPane`, it happens properly. Why is it giving me problem with `Label` only?

Isn't Label a Node?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you are not using [java.awt.Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html)  instead of [javafx.scene.control.Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) ? And yes [Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) is [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).

[image]

Comment: A best and clear answer, i had the same problem. We have to make sure what we are importing, because Eclipse imports Classes when we're typing.